# Windows store application to authenticate against azure function

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I'm trying to replicate the following example https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-windows-store (a Windows store application authenticating against azure AD), but I'm replacing the Web App by an Azure Function.

In the Function, the code checking whether the user is logged in is the following:

```
ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope").Value.Contains("user_impersonation"))
```

but this does not contain the required values, and  other calls don't return any value either (e.g. ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName));

Do you have any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't relative to whether the code run in web App or Azure Function. The root reason is that the difference parameter/way you acquire the token.

When you protect the Azure function with Azure AD and associate the token with the request, it also parse the token and read the claims in the token and construct the `ClaimsPrincipal` object.

You can parse the token in [this site](https://jwt.io/) to check whether the claims you expected in the token.

Answer (score 0):

See this issue https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon/issues/1

That scope is not in the claims list. You can try the following to dump all the claims you get and see what's available.

```cs
foreach (Claim claim in ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims)
{
   log.Info("CLAIM TYPE: " + claim.Type + "; CLAIM VALUE: " + claim.Value);
}
```